# empty err object in nodejs mongoose application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm writing a simple RESTful API using mongoose and their CRUD operations.

It "works", when i fire a post request (the only type of request for now) to the server it returns me an error 500 (*as it should be*) but the error object are empty and the server logger returns me an OK 200 state:

```
POST /omi/v1/clientes 200 17.586 ms - 25 // server: all is cool!


{
    "status": 500,
    "error": {}
} // response: nope, nothing is cool, baby, but i don't tell you why, or what.
```

I never seen this behavior before (*i admit it, i'm noob*) but reading my code i can't find the problem... here it is:

**clientes.js**

```
"use strict";

// instancias de modelos
var Cliente = require('../models/models').Cliente;
// var reqHelper = require('./util');

var clientes = {

  crear: function (req, res) {

    var nuevoCliente = {
      _id: req.body._id,
      nombre: req.body.nombre,
      direccion: req.body.direccion,
      telefono: req.body.telefono
    };

    Cliente.create(nuevoCliente, function (err, cliente) {
      if (err) return res.json({status: 500, error: err});
      res.json({ status: 200, cliente: cliente });
    }); // fin Cliente.create
  }, // fin crearCliente

  actualizar: function(req, res) {
    var ci = req.body._id;

    var clienteData = {};
    // reqHelper(req.body, clienteData);

    Cliente.update({ _id: ci }, clienteData, function(err, cliente) {
      if (err) return res.json({status: 500, error: err});
      res.json({ status: 200, cliente: cliente });
    }); // fin Cliente.update
  }, //fin actualizarCliente

  borrar: function(req, res) {
    Cliente.remove({ _id: req.body._id }, function(err) {
      if (err) return res.json({status: 500, error: err});
      res.json({ status: 200, msg: 'Cliente borrado' });
    });
  }, // fin borrarCliente
}; // fin actions

module.exports = clientes;
```

**index.js**

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router();

var clientes = require('./clientes');
var items    = require('./items');

router.route('/clientes')
  .post(clientes.crear)
  .put(clientes.actualizar)
  .delete(clientes.borrar);

router.route('./items')
  .post(items.crear)
  .put(items.actualizar)
  .delete(items.borrar);

module.exports = router;
```

And this is it... thanks for any help/idea

Comment: The first thing: instead of line "if (err) return res.json({status: 500, error: err});" do simple "console.log(err)", and say if you will see the error IN CONSOLE. And the second thing: put in console log next thing: "req.body" to see what parameters you are getting from the client and check if they appropriate to your mongoose model.

Comment: @Simha I was sending the data as form-data and not as x-www-urlencoded ...

But I have a question: What is the difference between both? Do you have some documentation that i can read about it?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Here 2 links that can be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data and http://www.restfm.com/restfm-manual/web-api-reference-documentation/submitting-data/applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-and . This is the first thing, and the second in any case check what are you getting from client(do things that I told in first comment), and say: what you see in console?